# How do I strip down a URL into separate parts in Bash?

Tags: regex, bash, shell, awk, grep

I have a URL (https://example.com/someone/something) that I'd like to strip down into three variables:

- https://example.com/
- someone
- something

I'm wondering how I can do this in Bash using `grep` or `awk` or some other tool.

To clarify, I'm not asking if there's a way to get all three variables at one go. It's perfectly fine to run three separate commands for each variable. Something like,

```
URL="https://example.com/someone/something"

DOMAIN=$(echo ${URL} | <some wizardry here>)

USER=$(echo ${URL} | <some wizardry here>)

THING=$(echo ${URL} | <some wizardry here>)
```

Comment: is it mandatory to save the parts into variables, or you just want to output them on separate lines?

Comment: I'd like them as variables. So I suspect I'd have to run three separate commands for each variable.

Comment: you don't need to call multiple commands at all, it's redundant

Comment: I prefer readability over one liners that may be harder to read, unless the one liner is also more readable than that would be the best option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash

URL="https://example.com/someone/something"

DOMAIN=$(echo ${URL} | awk -F'/' '{print $1FS$2FS$3}')    
USER=$(echo ${URL} | awk -F'/' '{print $4}')    
THING=$(echo ${URL} | awk -F'/' '{print $5}')

echo $DOMAIN $USER $THING
```

output:

```
https://example.com someone something
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$ URL="https://example.com/someone/something"
$ IFS=' ' read DOMAIN USER THING <<< $(sed 's|/| |3g' <<< ${URL})
$ echo ${DOMAIN}
https://example.com
$ echo ${USER}
someone
$ echo ${THING}
something
```

Comment: I think the exclamation mark `!` is possible to be used in valid URLs according to RFC-1738, probably safer to use another delimiter?

Answer (score 1):

Pure  **`bash`** solution:

```
url_str="https://example.com/someone/something"
if [[ "$url_str" =~ ^(http.+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ ]]; then
    domain="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
    section1="${BASH_REMATCH[2]}"
    section2="${BASH_REMATCH[3]}"
fi
```

Results:

```
$ echo $domain 
https://example.com
$ echo $section1
someone
$ echo $section2
something
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this too,

```
URL="https://example.com/someone/something?test=a"

DOMAIN=$(echo "$URL" | python -c "from urlparse import urlparse;import sys; print urlparse(sys.stdin.read()).hostname")

USER=$(echo "$URL" | python -c "from urlparse import urlparse;import sys; print urlparse(sys.stdin.read()).path.split('/')[1]")

THING=$(echo "$URL" | python -c "from urlparse import urlparse;import sys; print urlparse(sys.stdin.read()).path.split('/')[2]")

QUERYSTRING=$(echo "$URL" | python -c "from urlparse import urlparse;import sys; print urlparse(sys.stdin.read()).query")
```

Answer (score 0):

Just bash :)

```
URL="https://example.com/someone/something"

regex='(https?://[^/]*)/([^/]*)/(.*)'

if [[ "$URL" =~ $regex ]]
then
  DOMAIN=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}

  UUSER=${BASH_REMATCH[2]}

  THING=${BASH_REMATCH[3]}
fi

echo "$DOMAIN -- $UUSER -- $THING"
```

I used UUSER to not be confused with the USER environment variable